# How ROS nodes communicate offline?

Tags: ros, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am able to use ROS nodes to communicate offline without the internet. The thing is isnt that they transfer data using TCP and ros master mange nodes using XMLRPC server.

Can anyone help to clear my understanding please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258806/how-ros-nodes-communicate-offline?/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2017-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2017-04-08**:
Why you need this? And offline means "local". Ros nodes are already communicating offline with TCP via localhost. If you need specific approaches; Take a look at: [Wikipedia - Inter Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a good observation. As pointed out by @Orhan Gazi Hafif, networking (TCP/IP in particular in your question) is one form of IPC. On your computer, ROS relies on your operating system's `localhost` network interface (i.e., `127.0.0.1`) for single-host communication. As a "bonus" , ROS has the (nearly transparent) capability for *distributed* computing, which isn't possible for other forms of IPC (e.g., shared memory -- although, see [nodelets](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) for one way to handle that).

You've found a rather rich topic with a lot of history -- for instance, the (unfortunately confusingly named) [ipc](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./IPC/) package came out of CMU (used in [CARMEN](http://carmen.sourceforge.net/) robotics software) in the mid-90s. Note that this topic is still relevant -- [ROS2](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/DDS-and-ROS-middleware-implementations) is going to use [DDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Distribution_Service) as its middleware layer.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1